# Difference between Scattering and Reflection

Tags: optics, reflection, scattering, definition

I am confused: What exactly is the difference between optical [scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering) and optical [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(physics))?

To me, both terms are distinguished by where we place the observation plane.

Reflection: Observation plane is normal to substrate -> we record only normal reflection

Scattering: Observation plane is a sphere -> we record reflection in all possible directions

Often, one can either compute reflection or scattering, but isn't scattering just a more general reflection?

Comment: They're very different. Have you done any research? You should have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering   Sunlight scatters in the atmosphere. If it were reflected, we wouldn't exist.